# Lucene not firing an exception when sorting on an unknown field

Tags: sorting, exception, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using "Hibernate search" to index my entities in a database.  Everything is okay, and the lucene engine works great!

I tried, successfully now, to detect when there is an invalid field in the query.  In this case, I found `org.hibernate.search.SearchException`, with a message that says "Unable to find field for..."  I am trying to do the same on the sort field, but the Lucene engine accepts any strings without firing an exception.

How can I fire an exception or detect and invalid sort field?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, get field list:

```
// get the full text entity manager
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

        // search factory
        SearchFactory searchFactory = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory();

        // valid field list
        org.apache.lucene.index.Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(searchFactory.getIndexReaderAccessor().open(className));
        List<String> validFieldList = IteratorUtils.toList(fields.iterator());
```

...and more later...

```
          if(validFieldList.contains(sortFilter)){
                SortField sortField = new SortField(sortFilter, SortField.Type.STRING, reverseSort);
                Sort sort = new Sort(sortField);
                jpaQuery.setSort(sort);
            } else
                throw new NoSearchFieldException("Unable to find sort field for attribute "+searchQuery.getSortOn());
        }
```

and throw an custom exception in this case

```
public class NoSearchFieldException  extends Exception {
public NoSearchFieldException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

/* Disable stack trace */
@Override
public Throwable fillInStackTrace()
{
    return this;
}}
```